# Help in finding these two limits: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (x^{-2}-x^{-1}) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (3^x-2^x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help me in explaining how to get the following results:

> $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (x^{-2}-x^{-1}) = \infty$

and

> $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (3^x-2^x) = \infty$

Comment: Thank you (Amzoti) for editing the question. I'm not sure how to activate the Latex arguments the posts

Comment: You can use L-hospital rule for the first limit and show that the limit tends to infinity. For the second limit you can use the $a^x$ expansion and then use limit on that series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints

$$==\;\;\;\;x^{-2}-x^{-1}=\frac{1-x}{x^2}\xrightarrow [x\to 0]{}\ldots$$

$$==\;\;\;\;3^x-2^x=3^x\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^x\right)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\ldots$$

Further hint:

$$|q|<1\Longrightarrow q^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Mathematics is so beautiful ...

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 3^x(1-(\frac{2}{3})^x)$

now as ${x\rightarrow\infty}$

$(\frac{2}{3})^x\rightarrow0$

and

$3^{x}\rightarrow \infty$

hence the final answer is $\infty$